# Android Studio compiling app but no longer updating on phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently built a release apk for the first time to put my app in the app store. Now that I've done that I've switched back to a debug build variant to continue working on the app. However, now when I try to run on my device nothing happens. The app does not open like it used to and when I open it I can see it has not been updated. If I try to run again, android studio says the app is still running and I have to restart it, but I can not see where it is running? The gradle build says:

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]

and that the build was successful, but I can't figure out how to get it on my phone.

I'm wondering if I accidentally altered a required setting when trying to get my release apk? (I didn't know how to do it at first so may have clicked the wrong thing at some point.) If anyone knows what setting I may have changed and how to switch it back that will be much appreciated. I'm running Android Studio 3.0.1

Edit: It used to say "Gradle build running" first when I ran the app and now it says "Gradle build using tasks"

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall release version of application from your phone and then install debug version again?

Comment: @ostojan I have uninstalled the release version and it's doing the same thing. Would uninstalling the debug version and rerunning it do anything?

Comment: adb uninstall <package-id>; ./gradlew installDebug

Comment: I haven't used release configuration yet so it was just the idea. My experience with Android tells me that removing and installing application again can make miracles.

Answer (score 0):

When you start release APK build process in Android Studio, it makes some configuration changes. In that one is **Build Variant** of APK from `debug` to `release`. Like below

[image: screenshot]

Maybe you forgot to change it back when start application in debug mode. Just change build variant from `release` to `debug` when you want test/update application in debug mode.

Above option can be found on bottom left hand side of Android Studio.

PS: When you start/use app in debug mode, uninstall release APK from your phone (if any).

Comment: That's a good point but I do have it running in debug mode so there must be some other issue. Any other ideas?